# Como enviar relatórios diários de emails bloqueados do ASSP para cada usuário?

Tags: email

Eu uso ASSP como servidor de filtro email.

Frequentemente os usuários do meu domínio solicitam relatórios de emails bloqueados (enviando email para o endereço configurado em "`Request Block Report (EmailBlockReport)`")

Contudo, eu gostaria de agendar diariamente o envio automático desse relatório sem que fosse necessária a requisição por parte do usuário final.

Configurei o parâmetro: `BlockReportFile` como: `file:files/blockreportlist.txt`

E inseri as seguintes linhas no meu arquivo `blockreportlist.txt`:

```
user1@mydomain.com=>user1@mydomain.com
user2@mydomain.com=>user2@mydomain.com
```

Porém, quando eu marco a opção "`Generate a BlockReport from BlockReportFile Now (BlockReportNow)`" e clico em "`Run now!`" a seguinte mensagem aparece:

```
*** Updated - task was started
```

Mas o relatório não é enviado para nenhum dos usuários, nem para o email configurado em "`Send Copy of Block-Reports TO (EmailBlockTo)`".

Alguém saberia dizer o que está acontecendo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A questão é que o assp agendado não envia nenhum relatório para o usuário `user1` se não houver nenhum email bloqueado para o usuário `user1`, ao contrário das requisições de relatório feitas por email, nas quais uma resposta é recebida informando que não há nenhum email bloqueado para o usuário `user1`.

O assp segue a filosofia "*no news, good news*"